# Continuous functions integral proof

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f$ is a continuous function  $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb R$ then show that  there exists a point $c \in (0,1)$ such that $$\int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_c^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm dx \leq  \int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Comment: Hi thanks for your response  how did we arrive at this inequality. I understood how to proceed after this

Comment: Just the general rule that $\int f(x) g(x) dx\leq \int max(f(x))g(x)dx$ for positive function $f(x)$.

Comment: Is $\ f(x)\ $ required to be positive? If so, that fact should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi i think here paul has taken the positive function as x ( since x lies in the interval 0 to 1 hence it is a positive function) and maximum value of x over the interval is 1 there in we get the inequality. Correct me if i'm making a mistake anywhere.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Paul The inequality in your first comment is equivalent to $\int_0^1 (1-x)f(x)dx \geq 0$, not true for every continuous function (take $f=-1$ for example)

Comment: But it's actually $\ f(x)\ $ which you need to be non-negative to imply  the inequality  $\ \int_0^1 xf(x)dx\le\int_0^1 f(x)dx\ $. If you take $\ f(x)<0\ $ , for instance, then $\ \int_0^1xf(x)dx>\int_0^1f(x)dx\ $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H^{\prime}(t)=\int_{t}^{1} f(x) d x$. Then integrating both sides yields: $\int_{0}^{1} x f(x) d x=\int_{0}^{1} H(x) d x$ Afterwards using integration by parts as you proposed in the comment:
$\int_{0}^{1} x f(x) d x=\int_{0}^{1} x\left(-H^{\prime}(x)\right) d x=-H(1)+\int_{0}^{1} H(x) d x=\int_{0}^{1} H(x) d x$\end{equation}
Using average value theorem \begin{equation}
\exists c \in(0,1)
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} H(x) d t=H(c), \text { s.t. } \int_{0}^{1} x f(x) d x=\int_{c}^{1} f(x) d x
\end{equation}

Comment: Hi i did'nt get the second step can you explain

Comment: You mean, average value theorem part

Comment: Thankyou so much! I got it.